# MS Blazor Server Application ASP.NET Core Web API Update Method is not Working

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Blazor and ASP.NET Core Web API. I am developing a product page to Test CRUD Operations. Create, Read functionality is working properly but the update function is not working. I tried many ways but no result. My final code is as follows,

At this point I am receiving following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgueH.png)

Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

In controller:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutTblProduct(string id, TblProduct tblProduct)
    {
        if (id != tblProduct.ProductCode)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(tblProduct).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TblProductExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

In Interface IProduct.cs

```
public interface IProduct
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TblAgency>> getAgencies();
    Task<IEnumerable<TblCategory>> getCategories();
    Task<IEnumerable<TblProductType>> getProductTypes();
    Task<IEnumerable<TblProduct>> getProducts();
    Task<TblProduct> CreateProduct(TblProduct newProduct);
    Task UpdateProduct(string id, TblProduct upDateProduct);
    Task<TblProduct> GetProduct(string productCode);
}
```

In `Product.cs` class:

```
public async Task UpdateProduct(string id, TblProduct upDateProduct)
{
    var result = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<TblProduct>("api/TblProducts/" + id, upDateProduct);
}
```

In `Product.razor`:

```
private async Task SubmitForm()
{
    newProdut.EnteredBy = "Admin";
    newProdut.BarCode = "0000000";

    if (SaveOption == false)
    {
        int response = Convert.ToInt32(await _product.CreateProduct(newProdut));
    }
    else
    {
        //await _product.UpdateProduct(newProdut, AppData.prCode);
        await _product.UpdateProduct(AppData.prCode, newProdut);
        SaveOption = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First welcome! Then provide your error as text not as an image please! Next can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: With a break point in you your controller are you hitting it? What are the error messages in the browser console? Should the method params for your controller be decorated with [FromBody] etc?

Comment: I break the code and check that the controller hit and in object its shows the complete data which is sent from the razor page its also tried to update the data in database but then it give the following error {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2023 10:04:51 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
}}

Comment: Is your problem solved ? from [error 500 at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Do you get the error at `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` ?  Do you want to add the Product to the database ?